# Does DHCP server assign IP addresses that are already assigned statically?

Tags: networking

Let's say the DHCP SCOPE IS 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.255. The DHCP server will normally assign IP addresses dynamically in a sequenced order. What is the next IP in the sequence has been assigned to a node statically. Is the DHCP going to recognize that the IP is in use although it was not assigned by the DHCP server itself? Or is it going to assign the IP regardless and in that case it would cause an IP conflict?

Logically I would say it won't assign the statically in use IP but I'm asking this question because I never read something about it. Please include references if possible.

Thank You!

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question. But anyway, if you would do a quick google search with your own title, you would find this: https://superuser.com/questions/900074/does-the-dhcp-server-know-about-static-ip-addresses

Comment: That's right.  It is not a programming question. The main reason why I asked this is because I had a debate with somebody on the comments section on a different posting

Comment: Thanks for the link tho. It helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can have IP conflits in you network if you assign direct in an computer in your network and the router (for example) decides to give the same IP to another machine.

What I usually do to have fixed ips in my server is put an IP reserv in my router, binding with the server MAC Addres.